# Extremely Grainy Renders - Render settings help

Tags: rendering, light

I know this question is probably asked a million times on this site, but I can't seem to get a good clean render. I have my preview at 200 samples, a min of 3 and a max of 12 light bounces. I don't understand why it is still so grainy, are there any settings that will make a huge difference?[image]

I'm still new to blender, so please bear with me.

Comment: There's not enough information to be able help you, could you add more details? How is your scene lit, what lights are present in the scene, what materials or shaders are you using, what are your world settings? 200 samples is generally considered low-ish for most scenes or for a final render.

Comment: This will likely be flagged as a duplicate question. But the quick answer is that 200 is very low samples. A pure diffuse material might get away with as few as 500, but for glass, you're going to need ~2,000+ depending on other settings.

Comment: My light source is just a simple Sun light so I could illuminate the render, I'm only using a diffuse shader and a glass one above it, and I haven't touched world settings so I would assume they would just be at default.

Comment: start by reading this post: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles

Comment: Please post your blend file so we can take a closer look.

Comment: This is most likely caused by the glass between the object and the light source. Sampling through glass negates a number of optimizations, which, depending on your scene, can have very drastic consequences. There are some approximations you can implement yourself to work around this. See this question: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/10434/599

Answer (score 1):

I have also had trouble reducing graininess. I use Blender to model buildings and graininess (noise) is always worse on interior scenes.

I don't believe there is one simple answer.

Certainly increasing the number of samples (to say, 1000) will help. 
If your scene includes glass you should ensure you are modelling it correctly (so that Shadow rays see a pure transparent shader).

I have always found graininess to be most severe when modelling an interior lit from outside (through apertures). My intuitive understanding of what is going on (which might not be correct) is that the randomly chosen light paths 'bouncing' off diffuse materials have trouble 'finding' the light sources. One pixel will find a light source, a neighbouring pixel might not. Increasing the number of samples gradually smooths this out.

There are other things you can do also (caustics, clamping, portals) but I am afraid I don't know enough to advise you reliably on those