# FIXED: Glossy Shader in cycles Render rendering with White particles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

For my project i made a model of a room inside of Google Sketchup (2014), which was then imported as a .dae file,
i added a plane to use as the mirror (because sketchup cannot raytrace (make mirror surfaces)).

I used www.chocofur.com/6-shadersamptextures.html for the nodes (specifically the 100% reflectivity one found there)

yet when it renders there are white particles left-over (which are not there without the "mirror")

[image: With Mirror]
[image]

EDIT: So i found a way to greatly reduce the fireflies, i did this by mixing two scenes, the end result now looks like this
[image]

Comment: How many samples are you using? Where are the light sources, what are their settings? What are the Sampling Render Settings set to? Which Integrator do you use? Or even better: Could you upload the scene to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ ?

Comment: try looking at this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39616/need-to-understand-how-to-show-reflected-light-well-with-cycles, it may help

Comment: Your mix shader is at a Fac of 1. Thus making the mix shader and the diffuse BSDF useless, since only the Glossy BSDF comes through. In reality, no object will be 100% glossy.

Comment: Those bright pixels are referred to as firelies read through these related links: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1703/how-to-reduce-fireflies-in-cycles and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/what-is-the-reason-cycles-creates-incorrectly-colored-firefly-artifact-pixels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fireflies were reduced via mixing two different scenes which were duplicates of each other, however one was rendered with a seed of 10 while the other had a seed of 0.
(Only 100 samples were used to test this so the quality is (hopefully) likely to go up when i do a full render with more samples)