# Laser-Beam Constraint over moving Mirrors?

Tags: objects, physics, workflow, transform-orientation

For a newbie, how is it done to bounce the red line accurately based on the current position of the moving mirroring objects in the scene?

I want to play around simulating mirror positions and seeing where the beam as accurately as possible goes.

[image]

Comment: We would love to help, but it is a little unclear what the problem is. Could you be more specific? 

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In your screenshot, where does the laser beam originate and what is the role of they cylinder?

Comment: Thanks for reply Brockmann, the laser can originate from any of it's end. The objects in the scene are meant as the mirrors, the faceted cylinder aswell.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to visualize reflection of a beam or ray](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/150277/how-to-visualize-reflection-of-a-beam-or-ray) (involves a bit of python though, I don't think there is a way without it) Also see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/109178/scan-plane-shadow/109468#109468

Comment: Thanks for your reply brockmann,
I added some info to the image.
Question going through my head also is, if a line with multiple vetrtex can be used, where one vertex is created automatically when hitting a mirror object. Where each vertex stays on the mirror, as long as the beam would hit a mirror. And now the next following vertex would be pointing in the appropriate direction, but ... if there is no other mirror object within distance n , the end vertex of the line would be at a distance x from the last mirror.

Comment: New screenshot at  http://files.panodome.com/uploads01/IMG_2021-09-28_14-23-25_1632810205.jpg

? How can I break / add paragraph in StackExchange
? How can I add more pictures in comments
? How can I answer to answers with longer text etc., when I hit answer my question it seems it wants to finalize the post as being answered then

Comment: yes, the suggested post seems to exactly answer the question, I'll try it out now

Comment: No problem. Instead of comments, please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your
question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) to add information to 
your post. Just hit enter for a new paragraph in your question. Recommend have a look into the help pages: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/

Comment: Might be interesting as well: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39663/laser-beam-pathway-with-refective-mirrors