# Blender 3.0 Laser Scan Effect (With Shadows)

Tags: python, shaders, lighting

im so excited, this is my first Stack Exchange question :)
everyday i discover more of the blender community and this is yet another great way to learn :)
thanks for reading through this.

my aim is to create a "Laser Ray" object that looks like these types of lasers in EEVEE for a video im making. it is very important to have the shadow portion of the laser for the effect im trying to achieve

images for reference:
[image: laser plane example]
[image: laser plane example 2]
[image: laser plane example 3]

I found an answer to something very similar posted [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/109178/scan-plane-shadow/194328#194328?newreg=fe2391394dc74f29a3d44a87d49067d1) in 2020,
i attempted to run the scripts posted there but unfortunately i did not get anything from them, if there are any python wizards here your help would be much appreciated.

thanks again for your help!

Comment: Hi. Please specify which of the script you tried running. It would also great to see the error console output.

Comment: thank you for replying Hezi, the scripts i am trying to run can be found here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/194328/141861

I don't know how to link them or post them properly as a comment, help with that would be appreciated as well. Thank you!